# Add Items to datatale per column instead of per row

Tags: vb.net, datatable

Half a day of searching made at least my data readable in a datagrid in a wpf app.
My problem is (or what in think is my problem) would be the adding of data in the columns I created.

My source of data is from a dictionary `of string, list(of string)` with my dictionary `key` as the header and the `List` as it's items, also the dictionary and it's content has no fixed length.

And to display my data I used the combination of `DataTable` and `DataGrid`

Here's my snippet

```
Dim files As New Dictionary(Of String, List(Of String))
Dim dt As New DataTable
For Each item As KeyValuePair(Of String, List(Of String)) In files
    dt.Columns.Add(item.Key)
    For Each file As String In item.Value
        Dim dr As DataRow = dt.NewRow
        dr(dt.Columns(item.Key).Ordinal) = file
        dt.Rows.Add(dr)
     Next
Next
DGrid.ItemsSource = dt.AsDataView
```

It works(somewhat), but as you all have guessed all the succeeding displayed column items after the last one starts where it ended last(looks like a stair).

so the question is do I have to change the way I store my data(dictionary) or I am missing something and this can work as there is a way to add data per column instead of rows?

**UPDATE**

It's not pretty and I know there is a better solution out there.

What I did first was to just render/instantiate the table and it's content

```
Dim dt As New DataTable
    For Each item As KeyValuePair(Of String, List(Of String)) In files
        dt.Columns.Add(item.Key)

        For Each file As String In item.Value
            Dim dr As DataRow = dt.NewRow
            dr(item.Key) = Nothing
            dt.Rows.Add(dr)
        Next
    Next
```

Then edit it's content:

```
For Each item As KeyValuePair(Of String, List(Of String)) In files
        For file_index As Integer = 0 To item.Value.Count - 1
            dt.Rows(file_index)(item.Key) = item.Value(file_index)
        Next
    Next
```

This is a bad solution but it works. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to reuse existing rows for this. And add new one only when you have more items then rows.

```
Dim Files As New Dictionary(Of String, List(Of String))
Dim T As New DataTable, R As DataRow
For Each Pair As KeyValuePair(Of String, List(Of String)) In Files
    T.Columns.Add(Pair.Key)
    For i As Integer = 0 To Pair.Value.Count - 1
        If i < T.Rows.Count Then
            R = T.Rows(i)  
        Else
            R = T.NewRow()
            T.Rows.Add(R)
        End If
        R(Pair.Key) = Pair.Value(i)
    Next
Next
```

Comment: I see, because It just kept on adding and without reusing. Neat